# Need help finishing JavaScript clock using seconds, images, <head>, and <div>

Tags: javascript, html, clock, seconds

I'm still sort of new to the world of JavaScript. I have a JS clock that uses images to display the time. I just need help finishing a few things. I've tried looking online but I can't seem to find anything useful. Any help will be appreciated.

1. I can't seem to get the "seconds" functionto work. I deleted them from the code listed here because it corrupts the rest of the JS and won't let the clock show.
2. I want the  to be in the  section with a  to hold the clock later on down the page. I do not want "div script /script /div"

JS file name: clock.js

Images files:
names: 0.png - 9.png, colon-1.png (for blinking light), colon-2.png (for blinking light), am.png, pm.png | size: 16x21

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
 <div id="clock"></div> <!-- where I want the clock JS to appear -->
 <!-- appears on the right side of the page 100px from the top -->
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// creates array of all digit images
var digit = new Array()
digit[0] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[1] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[2] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[3] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[4] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[5] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[6] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[7] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[8] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[9] = new Image(16, 21)
digit[10] = new Image(16, 21) // AM
digit[11] = new Image(16, 21) // PM
digit[12] = new Image(9, 21) // Light ":"
digit[13] = new Image(9, 21) // Dark ":"

// Assigns sources to the digital images #0-9
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {digit[i].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/" + i + ".png";}

// Assigns sources to the other image objects
digit[10].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/am.png";
digit[11].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/pm.png";
digit[12].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/colon-1.png";
digit[13].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/colon-2.png";


var hour1 = getHour (0);
var hour2 = getHour (1);
var minute1 = getMinute (0);
var minute2 = getMinute (1);
var ampm = getAmpm ();
var colon = false;
var start = document.images.length;
var openImage = "<img src=\"" + getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/";
var closeImage = ".png\">";

document.write(openImage + hour1 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + hour2 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + "C.gif\">"); //need to edit.
document.write(openImage + minute1 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + minute2 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + ((ampm == 10) ? "am" : "pm") + closeImage);

var timerID = null;
var timerRunning = false;

update ();

function setClock() {

    if (getHour (0) != hour1) {hour1 = getHour(0); document.images[start].src = digit[hour1].src;}
    if (getHour (1) != hour2) {hour2 = getHour(1); document.images[start + 1].src = digit[hour2].src;}

    colon = !colon

    if (!colon) document.images[start + 2].src = digit[13].src
    else document.images[start + 2].src = digit[12].src
    if (getMinute (0) != minute1) {minute1 = getMinute(0); document.images[start + 3].src = digit[minute1].src;}
    if (getMinute (1) != minute2) {minute2 = getMinute(1); document.images[start + 4].src = digit[minute2].src;}
    if (getAmpm () != ampm) {ampm = getAmpm(); document.images[start + 5].src = digit[ampm].src;}

    timerID = setTimeout("setClock()",1000);

 timerRunning = true;
}

function update () {
 stopClock ();
 setClock ();
}

// do not change these numbers
function getHour (place) {
 var now = new Date ();
 var hour = now.getHours ();

    if (hour >= 12) hour -= 12
    hour = (hour == 0) ? 12 : hour

    if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour

    hour += "";

    return parseInt (hour.charAt (place));
}

// do not change these numbers
function getMinute(place) {
    var now = new Date()
    var minute = now.getMinutes()
    if (minute < 10) minute = "0" + minute
    minute += "";
    return parseInt(minute.charAt(place));
}

// "return 10" = am, "return 11" = pm
function getAmpm () {
 var now = new Date ();
 var hour = now.getHours ();
 if (hour >= 12) return 11; return 10
}

function getPath (url) {
 lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf ("/");
 return url.substring (0, lastSlash + 1);
}

// Stops the clock if this is not present
function stopClock () {
 if (timerRunning); clearTimeout (timerID);
 timerRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: hey, would you be able to provide us with a demo so that we can see whats going on? (like a jsfiddle)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/31sfcrt5/8/. Images are not present. I had to hide the "document.write" code starting at line 45 for jsfiddle to take it.

Answer (score 0):

I used your codes and modified to the following:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="clock" style="position:absolute;float:right;top:100px;right:0px;">

<script>
// creates array of all digit images
var digit = new Array();
digit[0] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[1] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[2] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[3] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[4] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[5] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[6] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[7] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[8] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[9] = new Image(16, 21);
digit[10] = new Image(16, 21); // AM
digit[11] = new Image(16, 21); // PM
digit[12] = new Image(9, 21); // Light ":"
digit[13] = new Image(9, 21); // Dark ":"

// Assigns sources to the digital images #0-9
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    digit[i].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/" + i + ".png";
}

// Assigns sources to the other image objects
digit[10].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/am.png";
digit[11].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/pm.png";
digit[12].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/colon-1.png";
digit[13].src = getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/colon-2.png";

var hour1 = getHour (0);
var hour2 = getHour (1);
var minute1 = getMinute (0);
var minute2 = getMinute (1);
var ampm = getAmpm ();
var colon = false;

// get array substring of first clock image in document.images array
// number of images in document
var start = document.images.length;

// displays initial clock
var openImage = "<img src=\"" + getPath(location.href) + "img/clock/";
var closeImage = ".png\">";

document.write(openImage + hour1 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + hour2 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + "colon-1.png\">"); //need to edit.
document.write(openImage + minute1 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + minute2 + closeImage);
document.write(openImage + ((ampm == 10) ? "am" : "pm") + closeImage);

var timerID = null;
var timerRunning = false;

update ();

function setClock() {

    if (getHour(0) != hour1) {
        hour1 = getHour(0);
        document.images[start].src = digit[hour1].src;
    }

    if (getHour(1) != hour2) {
        hour2 = getHour(1);
        document.images[start + 1].src = digit[hour2].src;
    }

    colon = !colon;

    if (!colon)
        document.images[start + 2].src = digit[13].src;
    else
        document.images[start + 2].src = digit[12].src;

    if (getMinute(0) != minute1) {
        minute1 = getMinute(0);
        document.images[start + 3].src = digit[minute1].src;
    }

    if (getMinute(1) != minute2) {
        minute2 = getMinute(1);
        document.images[start + 4].src = digit[minute2].src;
    }

    if (getAmpm() != ampm) {
        ampm = getAmpm();
        document.images[start + 5].src = digit[ampm].src;
    }

    timerID = setTimeout("setClock()",1000);

    timerRunning = true;
}

function update () {
 stopClock ();
 setClock ();
}

// do not change these numbers
function getHour (place) {
 var now = new Date ();
 var hour = now.getHours ();

    if (hour >= 12)
        hour -= 12;
    hour = (hour == 0) ? 12 : hour;

    if (hour < 10)
        hour = "0" + hour;

    hour += "";

    return parseInt (hour.charAt (place));
}

// do not change these numbers
function getMinute(place) {
    var now = new Date();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    if (minute < 10) 
        minute = "0" + minute;
    minute += "";
    return parseInt(minute.charAt(place));
}

// "return 10" = am, "return 11" = pm
function getAmpm () {
 var now = new Date ();
 var hour = now.getHours ();
 if (hour >= 12)
    return 11;
 return 10;
}

function getPath (url) {
 //lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf ("/");
 //return url.substring (0, lastSlash + 1);
 return "";
}

// Stops the clock if this is not present
function stopClock () {
 if (timerRunning) clearTimeout (timerID);
 timerRunning = false;
}

</script>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I think you can mofidy the getPath() function according to your need. For me, I don't need it as I'm running the codes with the images in my localhost. Hope this helps!